# WebAPI - Why is the HttpRequestMessage null for some HttpRequests

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I have a simple WebAPI controller. I've added the AutoMapper nuget package for mapping between a DataModel type and a corresponding Dto type like so:

```
namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
  public class Contact
  {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  public class ContactDto
  {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  public class ValuesController : ApiController
  {
      public ValuesController()
      {
        SetupMaps();
      }

      private void SetupMaps()
      {  
         Mapper.CreateMap<ContactDto, Contact>();
         Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, ContactDto>()
            .AfterMap((c, d) =>
                {
                    //Need to do some processing here
                    if (Request == null)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("Request was null!");
                    }
                }
        );
      }

      public ContactDto Get(int id)
      {
        Contact c = new Contact { ID = id, Name = "test" };
        ContactDto dto = Mapper.Map<Contact, ContactDto>(c);
        return dto;
      }
   }
 }
```

I'd like to run some logic after the mapping completes and need to use the HttpRequestMessage object in "AfterMap"

When I hit the ValuesController from Fiddler it returns the JSON representation of the Dto as expected.
The fun begins if I issue a bunch of simultaneous requests to simulate load and hit the endpoint;
Some requests succeed and some fail because the "Request" property of the HttpController is null!
Question is why is the Request null?

I have also tried using async controller methods and the behavior is identical:

```
    private async Task<Contact> GetContact(int id)
    {
        Task<Contact> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<Contact>(
            () => new Contact { ID = id, Name = "test" }
            );
        return await task;
    }
    public async Task<ContactDto> Get(int id)
    {
        Contact c = await GetContact(id);
        ContactDto dto = Mapper.Map<Contact, ContactDto>(c);
        return dto;
    }
```

I've attached a screenshot of the Fiddler calls indicating some requests succeeding with a 200 and the debugger break in Visual studio when the calls fails when the HttpRequestMessage is null.

[image: Fiddler calls]

[image: Debugger breaking-1]

[image: Debugger breaking-2]

Any insights as to why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you are supposed to use the `Request` property from the constructor. Controllers can be initialized before the context is available.

Try refactoring the `AfterMap` delegate into a separate method and calling it after the `ContactDto dto = Mapper.Map<Contact, ContactDto>(c);` call.

Comment: AfterMap is not invoked from the constructor. The ctor is just setting up the map. The AfterMap is invoked in the controller Get method after the mapping operation completes so it is still in the context of the GET method. As I said, this works for some requests and fails for others

Comment: No, but you are capturing Request into the lambda in the constructor. So if Request is null when the constructor is run, it's null whenever your AfterMap lambda is run.